# Angular - loading similar route in next workflow stage does not load main object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular-router

Here is an angular 10 SPA application with skip location change = false.

Main component --> Grid --> Open request page. Page opens, data loads, and is saved to DB. Request moves to next workflow stage. Loads grid again. This new request is on top with new workflow stage.

Now, straightway open the same request again in view mode. API URLs are hit, latest data comes from API. But in angular app, inside a component, latest data is not bound, unless page is refreshed.

This issue comes when same request is submitted in first step and opened in next step. If any other request is opened, and then user comes back to this one again, everything works fine.

The data provided by API is loaded via .subscribe.

Things that have been tried:

1. Loading component data in AfterViewInit, AfterContentInit, constructor.
2. routeStrategy.useSameRoute
3. router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload'
4. this.router.events.pipe(
   filter((event: RouterEvent) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
   takeUntil(this.destroyed)
   ).subscribe(() => {
   this.fetchData();
   });

Now, reading through this.

https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/refresh-current-route-in-angular-512a19d58f6e

Is there a simpler and direct way to bind all UI components again with data fetched from API?

Comment: Maybe try using ChangeDetectorRef to update UI `subscribe(() => { this.fetchData(); this.cd.detectChanges });`
https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

Comment: Tried this in AfterViewInit, and AfterContentInit